# Soundcloud api full length track

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, integration, soundcloud

I have the following question, which I didn't find answer to on soundcloud website or forum.

My plan is to use **Soundcloud Javascript SDK** to control custom player on a website and play sounds by url. I have looked at documentation and except **15 000 quota** limit didn't read about any other restrictions.

Questions is *"What will user hear"* when playing sounds from my website? Is user going to hear full track/sound or 30 sec preview only? Where can I get this information from?

**Here is screenshot from SoundCloud website:**
[image]
Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any track that has the property `streamable = true` can be streamed in full length using the api. The `streamable` property is set by the uploader with the 'enable app playback' option. This option is on by default, so most tracks are streamable.